# What does "with both classmates and teachers" modify? How to parse this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, complements, modifiers

> We worry about our friendship **with both classmates and teachers**.

Is the phrase *with both classmates and teachers* a complement of "our friendship" or a modifier?

Comment: What is the part that makes you unable to parse the sentence? It's quite obvious that you know that *with both classmates and teachers* is a constituent (a phrase, in the example).

Comment: Is it "with both classmates and teachers"  a complement of "our friendship" or a modifier?

Comment: That's a good linguistic question. I'm sure there are some users who welcome this kind of question, though IMHO it's not really important for English language learners.

Answer (score 1):

It's a prepositional phrase that is a postmodifier in the phrase *our friendship with both classmates and teachers*.